# What does MSDN mean when it says some API is not supported?

Tags: windows, msdn

Consider the [`SHGetSpecialFolderPath` MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762204%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). At the very top of the page, it says:

> SHGetSpecialFolderPath is not supported. Instead, use ShGetFolderPath.

Does this mean that this function = possible disaster for newer versions of Windows?

Also, the same page, at the bottom says:

> End of client support : Windows 2000 Professional

But I used `SHGetSpecialFolderPath` with success in Windows XP, Windows 7 and Windows 8 (32 and 64 bit). I get the feeling that MSDN isn't entirely accurate. Can anybody confirm this?

Comment: Unsupported means exactly that: no support. No guarantees. If you use it and it breaks, you keep the pieces. Don't go contacting Microsoft about it, and don't count on that function working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that `SHGetSpecialFolderPath` is an unsupported function and should not be used even though it's available in the library for backwards compatibility.  You should click on the function ShGetFolderPath and read up on the fact that even that is being retired and has been marked `deprecated` because eventually CSIDL_ constants are being retired.  `ShGetFolderPath` is a wrapper around ShGetKnownFolderPath.

MSDN documentation is canonical, you cannot assume that it isn't accurate.

So :-) read up Anish.

Comment: Hmmm okay I guess I misunderstood the word "support". I took it to mean that the function will work on a given OS. Turns out that it means that Microsoft isn't responsible for those functions anymore. Am I right?